# Did gaming.SE reserve/purchase the ME3 Rifle Replicas already?

Tags: discussion, contests, me3missions

I want the M-8 Avenger replica Rifle if I get Fleet Admiral but the guns are [sold out at EA's store](http://biowarestore.com/accessories/m8-avenger-assault-rifle-replica). Did SE reserve or already purchase some guns so winners can get the guns, or is the TV the only prize remaining?  The site mentions:

> Limited Edition of 500 made.

So barring an additional production run, that's it.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken (which is entirely possible), we didn't get the kickass rifles in time before they sold out. Lauren or Seth will confirm (or refute). If it is indeed the case that we're tragically rifle-less, we'll pick another (equally awesome) prize option to replace it, so never fear.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Ohhh, if I win I'm SO going to SE headquarters and yelling WHERE'S MY ELEPHANT. For like a WEEK.

Comment: @BenBrocka Really... an Elephant would do it for you?

Comment: @James http://whereselephants.ytmnd.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we probably won't be able to get our hands on any of these puppies- they sold out of 'em so fast! But, alas, if you complete Mission 6, we'll figure out some pretty sweet and potentially even more militaristic alternatives, or you may have your pick of the rest of the prize page.

Comment: Fair warning: Unlike Ben, I actually *am* close enough to StackHQ to show up at the office yelling *WHERE'S MY ELEPHANT.* I know where you work!

Comment: I can confirm that LessPop_MoreFizz has been to the office and knows where it is.  We may need to move.

Comment: I've got a baby on the way. My vote: $500 worth of diapers! Don't have a baby? That shouldn't stop you! You could get yours adult-sized so you never have to stop gaming!

Comment: How about just cash? Make a career out of g.se contests.

Comment: @Resorath *whistles nonchalantly*

Comment: @Sterno if the prize is delivered and fulfilled by Amazon, you can return it and get store credit (Amazon credit is nearly as good as cash nowadays) minus the cost of shipping.